# Is there a way to disable the friendly error message when installing Windows Server 2012 R2?

Tags: installation, windows-server-2012-r2, drivers

I have a server that is 3 years old that may have a driver issue when installing Windows 2012R2. The problem is, during the installation right before the installer begins copying files and right after a controller driver is selected, a Windows error message pops up and says something went wrong and the machine has to be rebooted. No blue screen or any possible indication of what the problem might be is displayed. Rebooting the machine simply starts the installation all over again.
Because Windows has not been installed, there is no place to store any kind of data that may contain the particular error (since it never gets to the point of formatting the drive to store such info).

Windows 2008, 2008R2, and 2012 installed with no errors (I tested these OSes all afternoon yesterday to see if there were any hardware or driver issues, but 2012R2 is the only one that crashes during install).

The friendly error message is incredibly ambiguous and serves no purpose to IT people trying to solve an installation problem. HOW do you disable it? (I disabled the automatic reboot when errors occur, but the same, stupid message shows up). I want my blue screen back with all the data to show!!!!

Comment: Can you at least copy what is written on the screen?

Comment: You might want to try an updated install media, might fix your issue. Look for en_windows_server_2012_r2_vl_with_update_x64_dvd_6052766.iso (most recent one I can see in my MSDN subscription).

Comment: Nothing is written on the screen except that it ran into a problem and needs to restart. (with the corny frown emoticon)

Comment: I'll try an updated install media next. How to disable the corny, useless error message? The old blue screen would at least give you some data in hexadecimal and maybe a device id.

Comment: "Your computer ran into a problem and needs to restart"
"It's collecting error info and will restart in (0) seconds."

Comment: I've narrowed it down to the SAS controller chip, the SAS cables, the backplane, the harddrives, the CPU, the memory and every other component of the server. <-- that was sarcasm.  Thanks MS for killing a perfectly good Server OS!

Comment: Ok, while this does not answer my question, it does help with my problem.
I discovered, to my horror, that my Supermicro servers (only 3 years old) do not support Windows 2012 nor 2012R2. So I'm screwed with extremely expensive paperweights!